# Spark job stuck in running state after calling sc.stop()

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive-metastore, spark-operator

I am running some pyspark workflows. When they finish I call sc.stop() and see that in the logs the following is printed:

```
22/09/03 00:37:17 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://bonfireoni-job-5158c78300c5b4fa-driver-svc.spark.svc:4040
22/09/03 00:37:17 INFO KubernetesClusterSchedulerBackend: Shutting down all executors
22/09/03 00:37:17 INFO KubernetesClusterSchedulerBackend$KubernetesDriverEndpoint: Asking each executor to shut down
22/09/03 00:37:17 WARN ExecutorPodsWatchSnapshotSource: Kubernetes client has been closed.
22/09/03 00:37:17 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
22/09/03 00:37:17 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
22/09/03 00:37:17 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
22/09/03 00:37:17 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
22/09/03 00:37:17 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
22/09/03 00:37:17 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
```

However when I run sparkctl list
I still see the sparkApplication as 'RUNNING' and it never turns to 'COMPLETED'

I have tracked this down to being related to when I use a hive metastore. If I do not use one, then it does not happen. However I can't figure out what to change to make it stop happening.

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this was to stop using JDBC to connect to my hive metastore postgreSQL server and instead bring up a standalone hive metastore in my k8s cluster and use a thrift url instead.